# How do you pass index into rowRenderer?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

https://codesandbox.io/s/qYEvQEl0

I try to render a list of draggables, everything seems fine only that I can't figure out how to pass 'index' into rowRenderer

If I do `rowRenderer=props => <Row {...props}/>`, `index` is passed in sucessfully.

But if I do:

`const SortableRow = SortableElement(Row)`

`rowRenderer=props => <SortableRow {...props}/>` ,

`index` is blocked somehow, failed to pass into `<Row/>`

Basically, I don't understand what can go wrong when you wrap your `<Row/>` component with a HOC? Why some props get to pass in, others not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the index into a different, custom prop...

```
rowRenderer = props => {
  console.log(props.index);
  return <SortableRow {...props} indexCopy={props.index} />;
};
```

Then, inside the child component, refer to this custom prop instead.

```
const Row = ({ indexCopy , style }) => {
  console.log(indexCopy);
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <span>drag</span>
      <input placeholder={'haha'} />
      <span>index={indexCopy || 'undefined'}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm not too familiar with HOCs, but I suspect that the `react-sortable-hoc` library is stripping out the implicit `index` and `key` values.  However, as long as you copy them over into their own custom props, you should be fine.

Comment: Hi, a separate question while you are at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775957/weird-interaction-react-virtualized-working-with-react-sortable-hoc