# Weird interaction 'react-virtualize'd working with 'react-sortable-hoc'

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

https://codesandbox.io/s/qYEvQEl0

So I wrote a demo myself that didn't work compare to one sample that works, the only difference being one props for `<List/>`

`rowHeight={({ index }) => 50}`

`rowHeight={50}`

I use the latter way ofc. And it is not working. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer copied from the [duplicate GitHub issue you filed](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/709) ;)

This creates a new function prop each time you render:

```
rowHeight={({ index }) => 50}
```

The prop-change is sufficient to trigger a re-render of the child component even if no other properties changed. In the second example above, no props change at all and so `List` doesn't know it needs to re-render. (Check out [the section on "pure components"](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized#pure-components) in the docs for more info.)

In this case, you could pass a small attribute that changes each time sort order changes (eg an incremented counter) to let the component know to re-render. You could also call `forceUpdate`.

Comment: While in the real project I use redux to manage states, the same rowHeight={({ index }) => 50} doesn't trigger re-render somehow. I'd like to know why? (Using props to pass redux state into List fixing it, but I;m still curious)

Comment: I don't know your project setup, sorry. Can't say.